# Como encontrar imagens e estilos CSS que não são usados num website?

Tags: html, css

Ao desenvolver sites de grande escala ou a retomar projectos de outras pessoas onde existem centenas ou milhares de linhas de estilos CSS, pode se tornar complicado rever e passar o código a limpo para remover imagens desnecessárias e estilos de `classes` e `ids` que nem sequer existem.

Então a minha pergunta é - existe alguma maneira ou ferramenta (para além dos erros da consola) para encontrar código CSS e imagens que não são utilizadas?

Deve haver alguma maneira de percorrer todos os ficheiros de um site e ver quais estilos e imagens não são carregados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veja esses dois plugins para firefox:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/

Veja essa ferramenta para remover estilos desnecessários: https://unused-css.com/

O projecto [Helium](https://github.com/geuis/helium-css) que está no github também pode lhe ajudar bastante já que tem o objetivo de remover CSSs inutilizados.

Answer (score 2):

Para complementar e atualizar a resposta, outros plugins

**Plugin Helion**

importe o plugin helion para seu site
 https://github.com/geuis/helium-css

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="helium.js" onload="helium.init()" async></script>
```

Irá aparecer um textbox como esse
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
basta clicar em **START** e ele irá analisar todos os CSS do seu site.

Com isto você poderá analisar que :

- Seletores na cor verde não estão sendo utilizados
- Seletores na cor preta estão sendo utilizados
- Seletores na cor azul, não puderam ser testados devido que eles só
  são ativados com alguma ação do usuário, por isto teste manualmente
  depois.
- Seletores na cor vermelha estão mal formados e prejudicando seu CSS,
  por isso faça correção ou delete-os.
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Chrome Plugin**

instale o 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unusedcss/dokggbghedajooenkgjbamikfgnngeik

**Outro plugin do chrome**, não testado mas interessante é:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-remove-and-combine/cdfmaaeapjmacolkojefhfollmphonoh

Ele exibe todos os cSS não utilizado e possibilita o download de um novo CSS só com os itens utilizados, bastando substituir o seu. porém como no helion deve tomar cuidado com os : hovers da vida